# functions in python .setdefault

Tags: python

need to return a customers spending on one particular day and in total.

My code:

```
def analysis(file: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
        with open(file, 'r') as files:
            for row in files:
                rows = [row.strip().split(',') for row in files]   
                customer_name = {row[0]:int(row[2]) for row in rows}
                dates = {row[3]:int(row[2]) for row in rows}
            if customer in customer_name:
                customer_expense = customer_name
            if date in dates:
                date_expense = dates
        
    return customer_expense, date_expense
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: There are many things wrong with your code. Start with this: In line 4, you are starting a loop over the rows in your file. Then inside this loop, you are looping again (for each row) to populate rows. After that, you loop twice again over rows (still in the `for row in filehand` loop).

Comment: `customer_name.get(customer, "Name not found")` instead of if statements?

Comment: Your `dates` dictionary won't work. You're not calculating a total for each date, just replacing the amount each time.

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel i still get the answer wrong sadly

Comment: I think `.setdefault` would be more useful (or faster) than `.get`:  create an empty dict `customer_name = {}`, then loop over rows: `for row in rows: customer_name.set_default(row[0], []).append(int(row[2]))`

Comment: @Swifty  have not learned .setdefault yet, so .get must be used.

Comment: Ok then: same start, but in the loop: `customer_name[row[0]] = customer_name.get(row[0], []) ; customer_name[row[0]].append(int(row[2]))` . Edit: I misread your question; what I wrote gives you the list of all expenses, not the total. See the proposed answer for that, or replace what I wrote with `customer_name[row[0]] = customer_name.get(row[0], 0) + int(row[2])`

Comment: @Swifty wait sorry do you mind implementing what you wrote into the entire code i wrote in the question? I am a  little confused.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're iterating over `filehand` twice -- once in the `for` loop, and again in the list comprehension that assigns to `rows`. You can only loop over a file once. Either process one row at a time in the main `for` loop, or create the `rows` list once with no `for` loop.
2. You're not totaling the amounts for each customer/date, you're replacing them. You have to check whether the name or date already exists, and either create or update it.

```
def customer_analysis(filename: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
    customer_name = {}
    dates = {}
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as filehand:
            for row in filehand:
                print(row)
                name, category, amount, rowdate = row.strip().split(',')
                amount = int(amount)
                if name in customer_name:
                    customer_name[name] += amount
                else:
                    customer_name[name] = amount
                if rowdate in dates:
                    dates[rowdate] += amount
                else:
                    dates[rowdate] = amount
            if customer in customer_name:
                customer_expense = customer_name[customer]
            else:
                return "Name not found"
            if date in dates:
                date_expense = dates[date]
            else:
                return "Date not found"
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "File not found"
        
    return customer_expense, date_expense
```

Creating those dictionaries is overkill if you're only interested in the matching rows. So you could just accumulate into total variabels when the row matches the customer or date.

```
def customer_analysis(filename: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
    customer_expense = 0
    customer_found = False
    date_expense = 0
    date_found = False
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as filehand:
            for row in filehand:
                print(row)
                name, category, amount, rowdate = row.strip().split(',')
                amount = int(amount)
                if name == customer:
                    customer_expense += amount
                    customer_found = True
                if rowdate == date:
                    date_expense += amount
                    date_found = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return "File not found"

    if not customer_found:
        return "Customer not found"
    if not date_found:
        return "Date not found"
        
    return customer_expense, date_expense
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a better structured and working version of what you wanted.
Note though that you're creating the whole dictionaries each time you call the function for just one name and/or one date, which is wasteful: it would be better to write 1 function to create the dictionaries, and another to interrogate them:

```
def customer_analysis(filename: str, customer: str, date: str) -> (float, float):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as filehand:
            rows = [row.strip().split(',') for row in filehand]
    except:
        return "File not found"
    
    # creating the dictionaries
    customer_name, dates = {}, {}
    for row in rows:
        customer_name[row[0]] = customer_name.get(row[0], 0) + int(row[2])
        dates[row[3]] = dates.get(row[3], 0) + int(row[2])

    # Interrogating the dictionaries
    customer_expense = customer_name.get(customer, "Name not found")
    date_expense = dates.get(date, "Date not found")

    return customer_expense, date_expense
```